# Mysql: fulltext and normal index

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I would like to know if it is OK to have both a fulltext index and a "normal" index on the same column (varchar) of a table in MySQL

If my understanding is correct normal index will be used for queries using "=" and "like" and the fulltext will only be used when i do "match()" ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is allowed to have several indexes on the same column, and while it is most of the time useless,  it makes perfect sense in your case.

MySQL will indeed use your `FULLTEXT` index when querying using `MATCH...AGAINST` syntax, and use the normal index for the rest.

Comment: thank you for your answer, is there a place in the MySQL doc where they mention this behavior ?

Comment: not really but its just a logical assumption:  When you have several indexes on the same column, it's the MySQL optimizer which choose the right one to use. If it doesnt use the right one, you can force the index you want with [HINTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html). However for `FULLTEXT` indexes, you should explicitly code your queries with the `MATCH...AGAINST` syntax because that tells the optimizer to use the corresponding  `FULLTEXT` index. So in your case it will just do exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: Our DBA has just confirmed what you have said as well :)

Comment: @sashok_bg c'est rassurant pour l'entreprise ;)